# How to select only details of min value only in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I could get the minimum percentage of two values, but I need only the name, and ID in the select.

```
ID     NAME           CITY           ONE      TWO
--------------------------------------------------
2      Morales      Los Angeles      40        10
1      John           New York       60        20
4      Mary          San Diego       10        10
```

I need to get the min value of one/two, and to only appear this as a result:

```
ID  NAME
---------
4   Mary
```

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output in the form of formatted text in your question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please read this.

Comment: How do you decide the minimum? For example, what if you add a row with 10,20 or 9,11? Is the minimum evaluated by ordering for ONE and then for TWO?

Comment: MIN(ONE/NULLIF(TWO,0))

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by ONE/TWO - do you mean the result of dividing the value from the ONE column by the value in the TWO column, with the result converted to NULL if the value in TWO is zero? That makes perfect sense, but it has nothing to do with the answer you selected as **Correct Answer**. Care to clarify?

Comment: And, regardless of the answer to the question above: if there are "ties" for minimum value, what should be returned? All the rows that have the minimum value, or only one of them - and if "only one", then which one? One possibility is "the one with the lowest (or highest) id"; another possibility is "a random one", i.e. "any of the rows with the lowest value for that ratio, I don't care which one".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select ID, NAME
from MYTABLE
where least(ONE,TWO) = (select min(least(ONE,TWO)) from MYTABLE);
```

If you don't want Morales, then you can do this :

```
Select ID, NAME
from MYTABLE
where id = 
    (select id from 
        (select id from MYTABLE order by least(ONE,TWO), ONE*TWO)
    where rownum <= 1);
```